# Blank Screen after login. Although virtual console works. Please help

Tags: debian, login, crunchbang, startx

A very frustrating thing happened today. To give you a little background, I had been running Dropbox and a few other programs prior on my CrunchBang box (Debian based).

It seems that some of the processes were taking more than the amount of memory I prefer. So, I performed a system reboot. Once the box came back to the login screen I entered my necessary credentials. After that, to my horror the screen went blank/dark grey!!!

I did a hard reboot as the box didn't seem to respond to commands. Once it came back I noted that it would let me switch to command line terminal view (virtual console). It appeared all my files where intact. But, I really need my GUI back.

Any ideas on what may have happened? Or what I might try to do to fix this? This CrunchBang install is only a few days old, it doesn't matter since it's not working. I've also tried launching the X server by running:

```
startx
```

Still nothing happens, just the blank screen. If I <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it terminates the X server and returns back to the command prompt.

**Solution UPDATE (11/22/13):**

Come to find out, my problem was simply that my default x-session-manager got switched to "lxsession" (which was configured to display a blank screen by default apparently). I'm not sure why but that's what happened. I'm thinking maybe one of the system updates changed the default x-session manager configuration. The following command allows you to change the defualt x-session manager(atleast in debian):

> sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager

Something like this will be the ouput:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative x-session-manager (providing /usr/bin/x-session-manager).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/lxsession         49        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/lxsession         49        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/openbox-session   40        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

The output of that command will allow you to switch between all installed x-session managers. Thanks all!

Comment: Could you post your `$HOME/.xsession-errors` file please?

Comment: when stuff like this used to happen to me, that first thing I always checked was my `$HOME/.xinitrc`.  Oh, and what window manager/desktop environment are you using?

Comment: @AlexejMagura Im running OpenBox. What is that file used for?

Comment: Sorry guys, those comments all seem like helpful suggestions, but since I last checked for responses I've re-installed CrunchBang Linux. It's working now. I will keep these suggestions in mind. Thanks a million. @AlexejMagura

Comment: This question should be closed because the OP reinstalled their system and the problem went away. This means there will never be a satisfactory answer and no follow up.

Comment: @AllenD you're very welcome. I am voting to close this since no follow up will be possible. If it happens again, please remember to include your `$HOME/.xsession-errors` file which is where this type of error should be logged.

Comment: @AllenD When a desktop environment is not being used--that is, when the user has to run either `startx` or `xinit` to start up the X Server--the file that contains most of the commands that are run after the X Server starts up are contained in `$HOME/.xinitrc`; depending on your window manager (and how you start your window manager), other files will also be referenced.  I would have at least tried running `xinit openbox` before giving up and reinstalling, since you can specify the program the X Server should try to use as a window manager/desktop environment.

Comment: @AllenD One should always make sure that their `$HOME/.xinitrc` file--if their starting X up from the command-line--contains only one command that isn't instructed to run in the background.  That is, all but one of the commands that you place in your `$HOME/.xinitrc` file should look something like this:  `xterm &`.  The `&` at the end says `run whatever precedes this as a background process`.

Comment: @AlexejMagura Unfortunately this issues started up again. The ".xinitrc" you have mentioned is not in my home directory or anywhere on my machine for that matter. I will try and figure out a way to paste the ".xsession-errors" output here. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: @terdon As mentioned earlier this issue has re-surfaced. You mentioned putting the "xsession-errors" output here. I will try and do this. Thanks.

Comment: @AllenD OK, I will nominate this for reopening. In the meantime, please post your `~/.xsession-errors` and add any other relevant information. Your `~/.xinitrc`may indeed be relevant if you use `xinit` but this is sounds more like a driver issue.

Comment: @terdon I'm not familiar with `startx` so I just assumed that it also sourced `~/.xinitrc` when it started the X Server.

@AllenD try running `xinit` or `xinit xterm` or maybe even `startx xterm`

Comment: @terdon FYI: Come to find out, my problem was simply that my default "x-session-manager" got switched to "lxsession" (which was configured to display a blank screen by default apparently). I'm not sure why but that's what happened. I'm thinking maybe one of the system updates changed the default x-session manager configuration. The following command allows you to change the defualt x-session manager(atleast in debian): `sudo update-alternatives --config x-session-manager` The output of that command will allow you to between all installed x-session managers. Thanks Everyone.

Comment: @AlexejMagura I'm glad this 2nd time I got hit with this issue I worked through this problem with your guys immense help. Thanks again. I hope this helps someone else. Note to any other "wannabe SysAdmins": Keep track of your updates, you never know what configuration might get changed.